# Paypal account for people with no legal first name / surname

Tags: paypal

Anyone has any idea of how to register for Paypal account if a person has only one, single-word legal name?

1) Paypal won't allow you to leave the "First Name" or "Last Name" column blank.

2) If you fill out both of the "First Name" or "Last Name" column with the single-word legal name, this become a problem as only the one single-word legal name is used in the bank account. As a result Paypal won't process any transfer to the bank account as the name doesn't match.

3) Tried contacting paypal, but no response so far.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a question for Paypal customer support.

Answer (score 2):

Contact their customer service. I bet it's not what you want to hear, but they will have the answers you seek.

They have a long wait time, but it's your only option.